# Error: name "Socketkind is not defind" with Flask-socketio?

Tags: python, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

I'm using flask-socketio to build a web-telnet. It's work well until I've added an object of class for telnet to another device in my local network. Anyone know how to resolve this problem?

**Here my code:**

```
import telnetlib
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit
app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app)
@socketio.on('check_device')
 def check(ip_add):
 device =  telnet_device(ip_add)
 device.connect()

class telnet_device():
  def __init__(self,ip_add):
        self.username  = 'user'
        self.password  = 'pass'
        self.host      = ip_add
        self.connection= False
        self.ketnoi    = ''

  def connect(self):
    try:
        self.ketnoi   = telnetlib.Telnet(self.host, timeout=15)
        self.ketnoi.write(self.username.encode()+b'\r')
        self.ketnoi.write(self.password.encode()+b'\r')
        self.ketnoi.expect([b'>',b']'],5)
        self.connection = True
        return True
   except Exception as error:
       print(error)
       return False
```

**And the error messages:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src\gevent\greenlet.py", line 766, in gevent._greenlet.Greenlet.run
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\socketio\server.py", line 599, in _handle_event_internal
    r = server._trigger_event(data[0], namespace, sid, *data[1:])
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\socketio\server.py", line 628, in _trigger_event
    return self.handlers[namespace][event](*args)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask_socketio\__init__.py", line 277, in _handler
    *args)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask_socketio\__init__.py", line 680, in _handle_event
    ret = handler(*args)
  File "D:\web_app\app.py", line 301, in kiemtra_olt
    device.connect()
  File "D:\web_app\telnettb.py", line 15, in connect
    self.ketnoi   = telnetlib.Telnet(self.host, timeout=15)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\telnetlib.py", line 221, in __init__
    self.open(host, port, timeout)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\telnetlib.py", line 237, in open
    self.sock = socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\gevent\socket.py", line 83, in create_connection
    addrs = list(getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\gevent\_socketcommon.py", line 218, in getaddrinfo
    in addrlist
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\gevent\_socketcommon.py", line 217, in <listcomp>
    for af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa
NameError: name 'SocketKind' is not defined
2019-05-27T08:41:52Z <Thread at 0x4e3c470: <bound method Server._handle_event_internal of <socketio.server.Server object at 0x044CEA70>>(<socketio.server.Server object at 0x044CEA70>, '626fb5231dba41c5be8a226f8f8240b9', ['check_device', 'ip_add'], '/', None)> failed with NameError
```

Comment: Don't snip the traceback. Where did this error happen? Show the full thing.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I've update details of error part :(

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using a version of Python that is too old. The `SocketKind` type was introduced in 3.4.3 according to [this issue](https://github.com/gevent/gevent/pull/1311). Are you using a 3.4.2 or older release? An upgrade to a newer Python should address your problem.